# Can I Delete AURA and GRANDPA?

Tags: substrate-node-template, grandpa, finality, aura

In [this](https://substrate.recipes/basic-pow.html) tutorial it is explained how to create a PoW node. Neither AURA nor GRANDPA are used throughout the tutorial. Also [here](https://substrate.recipes/basic-pow.html#:%7E:text=is%20never%20truly%20finalized%20and%20can%20always%20be%20reverted.) it's stated that such node will not finalize produced blocks.
The question is: Can I just delete AURA and GRANDPA from substrate node template and add my custom PoW implementation to get the same result? Will the node be running without finality?